# pdf kit like fastpdfkit for android

Tags: android, ios, pdf, pdf-viewer

I have created iPhone app where I am displaying PDF and playing audio and video files using fastpdfkit.

Now I want to make same app for Android also. Is there any kit for android where I can have same functionalities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`iText`](http://itextpdf.com/) is a dedicated java library to create and manipulate PDF documents. It has an Android version named [`iTextG`](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android). `iText` [tutorials](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples) are more available than for `iTextG`. So I suggest you to use `iText` tutorials.

`iTextG` is only for pdf manipulation. You can rely on Android multimedia API for audio and video support.

Comment: don't we have for android somewhat like fastpdfkit? one framework which will display pdf and play audio/ video files?

Comment: @FahimParkar I had the same problem with you. I just found Foxit and Adobe has some sdk that hase the same functionalities as fastpdfkit provided for Android.

Comment: @Berkay : is it free? can i have sample code please... also is it for iPhone app also?

Comment: @FahimParkar No they are not. Both have solutions for Android and iOS. But you have to contact with them to get demo files.

Comment: Changed DroidText to iTextG because A) DroidText has been discontinued and B) iTextG is the official port of iText.